# codeigniter deleting using ajax/query

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-2

I need help to delete a question and answer from the database. With the use of Ajax and jquery. The question and answer has id's to delete from the database. I struggling to delete a the answer and question from the database. Help would be appreciated. i Want to delete via Rest api method, getting the info for questions and answers and making echoing out a json

Comment: Not sure why your using $queryresult = for a delete.

Comment: im a beginner you see.